# Transforming Twilio library request into Guzzle request

Tags: php, twilio, guzzle, twilio-api, twilio-php

unfortunately our project runs on PHP 7.0 and we cannot upgrade it for now. And Twilio's library uses PHP 7.2+ on the version that contains the trusthub API support.

So I'm trying to do the request "Create EndUser of type: customer_profile_business_information" from this [doc page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/trust-hub/trusthub-rest-api/api-create-secondary-customer-profile?code-sample=code-create-enduser-of-type-customer_profile_business_information&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json) using Guzzle instead of their library, and I'm following instructions from the curl example.

Everything worked well except the Attributes field that looks like it's being ignored, it's returning a blank object and of course on their interface it's also not showing.

So in case the link breaks, the curl code example is the following:

```
ATTRIBUTES=$(cat << EOF
{
    "business_identity": "direct_customer",
    "business_industry": "EDUCATION",
    "business_name": "acme business",
    "business_regions_of_operation": "USA_AND_CANADA",
    "business_registration_identifier": "DUNS",
    "business_registration_number": "123456789",
    "business_type": "Partnership",
    "social_media_profile_urls": "",
    "website_url": "test.com"
}
EOF
)

curl -X POST https://trusthub.twilio.com/v1/EndUsers \
--data-urlencode "Attributes=$ATTRIBUTES" \
--data-urlencode "FriendlyName=friendly name" \
--data-urlencode "Type=customer_profile_business_information" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

And here's the PHP code that I made:

```
<?php
// $company is a model
$token = base64_encode(\Config::get('twilio.accountSid') . ':' . \Config::get('twilio.authToken'));
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://trusthub.twilio.com/v1/', 'headers' => ['Authorization' => "Basic {$token}", 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']]);
$client->post("EndUsers", [
    'form_params' => [
        'FriendlyName' => $company->business_name,
        'Type' => 'customer_profile_business_information',
        'Attributes' => [
            'business_name' => $company->business_name,
            'business_identity' => 'direct_customer',
            'business_type' => $company->business_type,
            'business_industry' => $company->industry->twilio_name,
            'business_registration_identifier' => 'EIN',
            'business_registration_number' => $company->tax_id_number,
            'business_regions_of_operation' => $company->region,
            'website_url' => $company->website,
            'social_media_profile_urls' => '',
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Is there something I'm missing here that it's not saving the `Attributes` data?

PS: the other fields (FriendlyName and Type) are being successfully saved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `Attributes` property of Twilio resources tends to be a JSON string, and  I think that's the case for this one too. So, rather than passing an array of attributes, you need to `json_encode` the array first. This should work for you:

```php
<?php
// $company is a model
$token = base64_encode(\Config::get('twilio.accountSid') . ':' . \Config::get('twilio.authToken'));
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://trusthub.twilio.com/v1/', 'headers' => ['Authorization' => "Basic {$token}", 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']]);
$client->post("EndUsers", [
    'form_params' => [
        'FriendlyName' => $company->business_name,
        'Type' => 'customer_profile_business_information',
        'Attributes' => json_encode([
            'business_name' => $company->business_name,
            'business_identity' => 'direct_customer',
            'business_type' => $company->business_type,
            'business_industry' => $company->industry->twilio_name,
            'business_registration_identifier' => 'EIN',
            'business_registration_number' => $company->tax_id_number,
            'business_regions_of_operation' => $company->region,
            'website_url' => $company->website,
            'social_media_profile_urls' => '',
        ])
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I've tried that before, and got the error 20500 (Twilio Internal Server Error)

Comment: Oh, weird. I mean, that's [what the Twilio PHP library does too](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/main/src/Twilio/Rest/Trusthub/V1/EndUserList.php#L51) so I'm not sure what else to suggest. Can you try it again with the above code?

Comment: Yeah, just did it and got same 20500 error :(

Comment: Are you able to make the example request using `curl`? With the example data or with your own data? It might be that the best thing to do is [contact Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) as a 20500 error is on the Twilio side of things.

Comment: Yes using curl on the terminal as per in the docs works fine. And yeah I opened a ticket to their support a while ago, still waiting to hear back from them. I'll dig in a bit more on Twilio library to see if I spot anything that they do different. Thanks for trying to help me tho :)

Comment: If you want to email the ticket number to me at philnash at twilio dot com I can try to follow up on it internally. Even if you're not making the request right, you should get a 400 error, not a 500. So I'd like to see this fixed too!

Comment: I've fixed it, turns out your solution of adding json_encode was correct. My problem was that the field `$company->region` returns an array in case of multiple regions, and the API wasn't throwing the correct error nor giving me a message of unsupported value. So after I changed to this `'business_regions_of_operation' => implode(',', $company->region), ` it fixed the 20500 error :)
Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted!

Comment: I'm following up to try to fix the 20500 error now.